# How to filter properties in json data in Google Maps API v.3 with select?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to filter properties in json data in google maps api with select.

I've seen a few examples here but I have not found an example that loads a **external file json** and filter the properties.

Here, I'm working on an example of developers.google. My problem is in the filters in java file. I have not found a way to do this yet.

I want to filter out the magnitude of earthquakes.

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

See please: http://jsfiddle.net/Alisson_BRA/9dzj49op/1/

Full JSON: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js

JSON (sample), HTML and JS:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "mag": 5.4,
                "place": "48km SSE of Pondaguitan, Philippines",
                "status": "AUTOMATIC" },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [126.3832, 5.9775] },
                },
                 {
             "type": "Feature",
             "properties": {
                "mag": 5.7,
                "place": "35km ESE of Ndoi Island, Fiji",
                "status": "REVIEWED" },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-178.3725, -20.753] },
              },
            ]
}
```

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      var gmarkers1 = [];
      var markers1 = [];
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
          mapTypeId: 'terrain',
          streetViewControl: false,                         
          mapTypeControl: false
        });

        var script = document.createElement('script');

        script.src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }

      window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
          var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
          });
        }
      }

      gmarkers1.push(marker1);

// Function to filter markers by category

    filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];

        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
    }

    </script>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

    <div class="mapWrap">
      <div id="map"></div>

      <div class="investCast">

        <select id="mag" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">  
        <option value="">Selected the magnitude</option>
        <!-- value="4.5=<" Is this correct? I want to load all the values less or equal than 4.5 -->
        <option value="4.5=<">Less than or equal 4.5</option>
        <!-- value="4.6 to 4.9=<" Is this correct? I want to load all the values between 4.6 to 4.9 -->
        <option value="4.6 to 4.9">Between 4.6 and 4.9</option>
        <!-- value="4.6 to 4.9=<" Is this correct? I want to load all the values greater or equal 5 -->
        <option value=">=5">Greater than or equal 5</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading all the markers on the map to start.  One option to filter them, would be to add the data you want to filter them on to the marker (as a property):

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
  var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);

  //Creating a marker and putting it on the map, add magnitude as a "custom property"
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    mag: results.features[i].properties.mag
  });
  gmarkers.push(marker);
}
```

Then filter the markers by that value:

```
// Function to filter markers by category
var filterMarkers = function(category) {
  switch (category) {
    case "4.5=<":
      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.mag <= 4.5) {
          marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
          marker.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      break;
    case "4.6 to 4.9":
      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (4.6 <= marker.mag && marker.mag <= 4.5) {
          marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
          marker.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      break;
    case ">=5":
      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (5 <= marker.mag) {
          marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
          marker.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers[i];
        marker.setVisible(true);
      }
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9dzj49op/2/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers = [];
var markers = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
  // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
  script.src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

// Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
// set of coordinates.
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
    var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);

    //Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      title: "" + results.features[i].properties.mag,
      mag: results.features[i].properties.mag
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
  }
}

// Function to filter markers by category
var filterMarkers = function(category) {
  console.log("category=" + category);
  switch (category) {
    case "4.5=<":
      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.mag <= 4.5) {
          marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
          marker.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      break;
    case "4.6 to 4.9":
      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (4.6 <= marker.mag && marker.mag <= 4.5) {
          marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
          marker.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      break;
    case ">=5":
      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (5 <= marker.mag) {
          marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
          marker.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers[i];
        marker.setVisible(true);
      }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>

<div class="mapWrap">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  <div class="investCast">

    <select id="mag" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
      <option value="">Selected the magnitude</option>
      <option value="4.5=<">Less than or equal 4.5</option>
      <option value="4.6 to 4.9">Between 4.6 and 4.9</option>
      <option value=">=5">Greater than or equal 5</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` to transform one array into another, including elements based on a condition:

```js
const input = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.4,"place":"48km SSE of Pondaguitan, Philippines","time":1348176066,"tz":480,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usc000csx3","felt":2,"cdi":3.4,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":"449","net":"us","code":"c000csx3","ids":",usc000csx3,","sources":",us,","types":",dyfi,eq-location-map,general-link,geoserve,historical-moment-tensor-map,historical-seismicity-map,nearby-cities,origin,p-wave-travel-times,phase-data,scitech-link,tectonic-summary,"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[126.3832,5.9775,111.16]},"id":"usc000csx3"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.7,"place":"35km ESE of Ndoi Island, Fiji","time":1348175020,"tz":-720,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usc000csw5","felt":0,"cdi":1,"mmi":2,"alert":"green","status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":"500","net":"us","code":"c000csw5","ids":",usc000csw5,","sources":",us,","types":",dyfi,eq-location-map,geoserve,historical-moment-tensor-map,historical-seismicity-map,losspager,nearby-cities,origin,p-wave-travel-times,phase-data,scitech-link,shakemap,tectonic-summary,"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-178.3725,-20.753,544.19]},"id":"usc000csw5"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":3.8,"place":"43km NNE of Talkeetna, Alaska","time":1348174056,"tz":-480,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak10562838","felt":0,"cdi":1,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":"1","sig":"222","net":"ak","code":"10562838","ids":",ak10562838,at00mao1rc,","sources":",ak,at,","types":",dyfi,general-link,geoserve,impact-link,nearby-cities,origin,tectonic-summary,"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-149.8072,62.6916,10.1]},"id":"ak10562838"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":3.4,"place":"46km ESE of Yunaska Island, Alaska","time":1348171278,"tz":-660,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak10562822","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":"178","net":"ak","code":"10562822","ids":",ak10562822,","sources":",ak,","types":",general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,tectonic-summary,"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-170.0567,52.4716,127.2]},"id":"ak10562822"},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":4.9,"place":"41km WSW of Kimbe, Papua New Guinea","time":1348163091,"tz":600,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usc000csng","felt":0,"cdi":1,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"REVIEWED","tsunami":null,"sig":"369","net":"us","code":"c000csng","ids":",usc000csng,","sources":",us,","types":",dyfi,eq-location-map,general-link,geoserve,historical-moment-tensor-map,historical-seismicity-map,nearby-cities,origin,p-wave-travel-times,phase-data,scitech-link,tectonic-summary,"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[149.8211,-5.7346,120.46]},"id":"usc000csng"}]};

const featuresBelowMag5 = input.features.filter(({ properties: { mag } }) => mag < 5);
console.log(featuresBelowMag5);
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance thanks for your response.

Sorry, but I'm not a developer, so I did not understand how to add your answer in my example.

Could you show me a complete example (html, js) in snippet or jsfiddle, please?

Remember that my json loads through a url.

Comment: The `input` variable corresponds to the object structure you provided - just press "Run code snippet" and you'll see how it filters out all those with larger magnitudes. Then you can pass the filtered object along as needed.